# programmatically UPDATE Details View C#

Tags: c#, detailsview

How can I programmatically Update Details View.  NOT through SQL DataSource or through Wizard. I want to Update the Details View from Code- Behind (.cs)

I have a Drop down list loaded with UserNames, Up on Selecting the UserNAME, I am loading the Details View with User Information.

Now I want to Provide Update feature programmtically.

How can I do this ?..

Comment: Do you want to let the user update details information? What are you using to render the information; Winform, Webform, MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an Update Panel around the Details View. Add an async postback trigger to the panel - the change event of the drop down.

Set the dropdown to autopostback.

You'll get the desired behavior without a full postback.

You might be able to do better, but this will work.

Comment: I am doing what you said, but my question is how to UPDATE the DetailsView Programemtically using C# ?

Comment: Use the event handler - dropdown's selectedindexchanged

Answer (score 0):

If you already displaying data on any form after drop down list selection, propably
you're using "SelectedIndexChanged" event.

```
 private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      // show user details for example by get the data from db
      string query = "SELECT userId, UserName FROM Users";
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("conn string");
      SqlCommand comd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
      conn.Open();
      using(SqlDataReader r = comd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while(r.Read()) 
          {                 
             sb.AppendLine(r.GetInt32(0) + ", " + r.GetString(1));                 
          }
          conn.Close();
      }
      textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
 }
```

perform to refresh data by seting desired index:

```
this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

it invokes SelectedIndexChanged envent and refresh user detailed information.

Of course you can do it more efficient.

[EDIT]

You can update data in database by displaying the detailed view in DataGridView control connected to db:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from users", conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

edit data in DataGridView and after all:

```
adapter.Update(ds);
```

done!

Comment: I want to Edit and Update the Values in to database from the DetailsView.. How can I do it, nothing to do with Dropdown I think ?..

Comment: Hey, I have 20 columns in User information. So, it would be not good those 20 fields in GridView as it will be a Horizontal row which will cross my page.  Sorry if I ask a Stupid Question, can I display Gridview Records in Vertical like DetailsView ??

Comment: You can do it by drop data form DataSource (table in DataBaseExplorer) in Visual Studio. If you don't have configured this type of db connection and you're doing everything manually you have to do manually map db fields to specified controls (textbox,combobox...) and put it on the form. After that, you can create your own class for managing mapped fields or use .NET DataTable class as a container. Now, after data changing, you can call Update method which can update db using data collected from form.